# Regex For PHP Code?

Tags: php, regex, drupal

I have the following code

```
<?
php drupal_set_message("Your registration submission has been received.");
drupal_goto("/events-initiatives/events-listing");
?>
```

And I want to remove everything but the `Your registration submission has been received.` and this message will change, so I need it to be a wildcard. So it would also make say

```
<?php

drupal_set_message("Testing!!!"); 
drupal_goto("/events-initiatives/events-listing"); 

?>
```

But I can't figure out how to do the PHP code, my current one is

```
preg_replace('#(<?php drupal_set_message(").*?("); drupal_goto("/guidelines-resources/professionals/lending-library"); ?>)#', '$1$2', $string);
```

but that isn't working, it seems to have problems with the ( in it.

Any idea how I could do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Drupal, but is that supposed to be a PCRE regex passed into the `drupal_set_message()` function?

Comment: Are you trying to do a regex to replace all occurrences of this in your code?  Otherwise, I don't see why you wouldn't just pass a variable into the drupal_set_message function, with that variable being whatever value you want the message to be.

Comment: Why did you guys downvote? And why did you remove the regex and replace it with something that it was not intended to be?

Comment: don't you have to escape the regex? like `drupal_set_message("\).*?\("); `. `(` and `)` mean groups...

Comment: It's reading that line from the database, and removing that stuff, so I can just display the text. Not the PHP code and extra garbage.

Comment: @Steven, I suggest you edit your question again and replace the regex that has been turned into a PHP code snippet.

Comment: Already done for him. People and their not understanding questions and their screwing with edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your original post, (before your regex was changed into a PHP snippet) I'd suggest you are looking for a regex along these lines:

`#<\?php\s+drupal_set_message\(".*?"\);\s+drupal_goto\("/guidelines-resources/professionals/lending-library"\);\s+\?>#`

Note that this regex:

- escapes all special characters (e.g., ?, ( and )) with preceding slashes
- replaces a single space with `\s+` which matches one or more consecutive whitespace characters

**EDIT**

After rereading your question, if the only thing you want left is the text that is passed as an argument to `drupal_set_message`, then try this:

```
$pattern = '#\bdrupal_set_message\("(.*?)"\)#';
$found = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

// if found, $matches[1] will contain the argument to drupal_set_message
```

Comment: Apparently this was really hard. People would much rather downvote, and make really dumb questions then answer it.

Comment: Be careful with unexpected strings like `"blah blah \"); ..."` which may match the rest of your regex.

Comment: That second one actually makes a lot of sense, not sure why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score -1):

You can escape the special characters (though really, just the open and close parentheses) with backslashes. On a side note, if you have a decent IDE then it should have sophisticated regex-capable search-and-replace; use it (although if you do, you'll probably need to also escape the forward slashes, as those are the most likely delimiters that your IDE would use).